# Sharing data across Sitecore pipelines

Tags: sitecore

I´m trying to perform some actions in the pipeline "httpRequestBegin" only when necessary. 
My processor is executed after Sitecore resolves the user (processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.UserResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" ), as i´m resolving the user too if Sitecore is not able to resolve it first.

Later, i want to add some rendering in the pipeline "insertRenderings", only if actions in the previous pipeline were executed (If i resolved the user, show a message), so i´m trying to save some "flag" in the first step, to check in the second.
My question is, where can I store that flag? I´m trying to find some kind of "per request" cache...

So far, I've tried:

- The session: Wrong, it's too early, session doesn't exists yet.
- Items (HttpContext.Current.Items): It doesn't work either, my item is not there on the seconds step.

So far i'm using the application cache (HttpContext.Current.Cache) with some unique key, but I don´t like this solution.

Anybody body knows a better approach to share this "flag"?

Comment: Could you update your question to flesh out what you're doing in httpRequestBegin? Also, where in httpRequestBegin the does your processor occur?

Comment: Question updated. I´m resolving the user just after the sitecore user resolved is executed.

Comment: Could you solve the problem by checking the active user in your insertrenderings processor (perhaps their domain or role)?

Comment: There isn't anything on the user properties telling me if "I" resolved it or sitecore did. I thought about adding some property to the profile, but i don't like the idea of having to store it phisically in the core database. Do you know if it's possible to save properties in memory and reuse them later?

Comment: Try using `Sitecore.Context.Items` collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a flag to the request header and then check it's existence in the latter pipelines, e.g.

```
// in HttpRequest pipeline
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("CustomUserResolve", "true");

// in InsertRenderings pipeline
var customUserResolve = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["CustomUserResolve"];
if (Sitecore.MainUtil.GetBool(customUserResolve, false))
{
    // custom logic goes here
}
```

This feels a *little* dirty, I think adding to `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Params` would been nicer but those are readonly. However, if you only need this for a one time deal (i.e. only the first time it is resolved) then it will work since in the next request the Headers are back to default without your custom header added.

Comment: I think this is your best bet. The problem is that all the other storage you can use (that I can think of) is shared across the application and thus not isolated for the request. (ab)using the request headers works great.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Cache` or `HttpRuntime.Cache` could be the fastest solution here. Though this approach would not preserve data when the AppPool gets recycled. 
If you add only a few keys to the cache and then maintain them, this solution might work for you. If each request puts an entry into the cache, it may eventually overflow the memory used by worker process in a long run.

As alternative to this you may try to use `Sitecore.Context.ClientData` property. It uses ClientDataStore that employs a database (look for `clientDataStore` section in the `web.config` file) to store data. These entries can survive the AppPool recycle.
Though if you use them a lot, it may become a bottleneck under the load when you need to write to and/or read from the entries.
If you do know that there could be a lot of entries created for sharing purposes, I'd create a scheduled task to clean up the data store from obsolete entries.

Comment: Don't think it's a very sensible idea to use application level caches.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Cache is the cache i'm currently using, and what i'm trying to avoid, as it's per application with a too wide scope, i just need something with a very small scope, as per request. App pool recycling is not a problem, as i just need the flag, to move from one point of the request to another, in fact i'm clearing the flag add the end of the process. I checked the ClientData, but... isn't it saved on the client / browser? I don't want to send anything to the client, as is an internal flag, useless at client side.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I just want post solution I worked around

Below will hold data per http request basis.
HttpContext.Current.Items["ModuleInfo"] = "Custom Module Info"

we can store data to httpcontext in one sitecore pipeline and retrieve in another...

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146455/When-Can-We-Use-HttpContext-Current-Items-to-Store